# JFreeChart - Showing/Hiding Subplots in a CombinedDomainXYPlot

Tags: java, plot, jfreechart, subplot

Is it possible to show/hide a Subplot in a CombinedDomainXYPlot without using "add" or "remove" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to add the subplot to the the chart, you can add it to a combined plot instead.   Of course that plot has to be added to a Chart.

Comment: Yes I agree with you, maybe my question was not well written. In fact, when you add several Subplots to a Combined, is there a way to show/hide them ?

Comment: Add/Remove is the way hide/show them.  There is not a setVisible type of method to turn viewing on or off.